# Maven to Eclipse (m2e) ignores compiler version setting in POM file in Kepler

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e, eclipse-kepler

Many people have posted complaints that m2e resets their compiler settings to 1.5. The answer to these complaints is often to  set the source and target levels as shown as below:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I am using Eclipse Kepler which come with m2e built in, and this does not work for me. I've checked for updates to m2e and there are none. Every time I select Maven > Update Project, my compiler version gets set back to 1.5 and I have to open the project setting and reset it to 1.7.

Is there something else that needs to be done or is this a bug in m2e for Kepler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you set it within the pluginManagement-tag?

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.1</version>
           <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```